# Unable to consume JAVA sdk for Google classroom API's getting PERMISSION_DENIED Request had insufficient authentication scopes

Tags: google-oauth, google-classroom, google-oauth-java-client

I am trying to integrate google classroom in my java project Using OAuth 2.0 for **Server to Server** authentication, example is given here [Official Google class room integration doc](https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/java) uses **OAuth consent screen authentication**, I altered the code  for **Server to Server** authentication with few changes

Progress so far:

- Created a Google App
- Enabled Google classroom API from Dashboard.
- Created Service Account Key (.p12) for server-to-server authentication(later used that in code along with Application name)

  ```
  public class Quickstart2 {
      private static final String APPLICATION_NAME ="MY_APP_NAME";
      private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY =
          JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
      private static HttpTransport httpTransport;

      /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
      private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;
      private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "ID_CREADED_ON_GOOGLE_APP";
      /** Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
       *
       * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
       * at ~/.credentials/classroom.googleapis.com-java-quickstart
       */
      private static final List<String> SCOPES =
          Arrays.asList(ClassroomScopes.CLASSROOM_COURSEWORK_ME);

      static {
          try {
              HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
          } catch (Throwable t) {
              t.printStackTrace();
              System.exit(1);
          }
      }

      /**
       * Creates an authorized Credential object.
       * @return an authorized Credential object.
       * @throws IOException
       * @throws GeneralSecurityException 
       */
      public static Credential authorize() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {  
          /* Added this code in given sample code for Server-to-server authentication*/


        httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("BULB-1cb9e145138b.p12"))
             .setServiceAccountUser("bulb-88@bulb-173512.iam.gserviceaccount.com") 
            .build();
        return credential;
      }

      /**
       * Build and return an authorized Classroom client service.
       * @return an authorized Classroom client service
       * @throws IOException
       * @throws GeneralSecurityException 
       */
      public static com.google.api.services.classroom.Classroom
              getClassroomService() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
          Credential credential = authorize();
          System.out.println("token   "+credential.getAccessToken());
          return new com.google.api.services.classroom.Classroom.Builder(
                  HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                  .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                  .build();
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
          // Build a new authorized API client service.
          com.google.api.services.classroom.Classroom service =
              getClassroomService();

          Course course = new Course()
          .setName("10th Grade Biology")
          .setSection("Period 2")
          .setDescriptionHeading("Welcome to 10th Grade Biology")
          .setDescription("test descriptioon")
          .setRoom("301")
          .setOwnerId("me")
          .setCourseState("PROVISIONED");
           course = service.courses().create(course).execute(); /* here I am getting the exception */


         //  List the first 10 courses that the user has access to.

          ListCoursesResponse response = service.courses().list()
              .setPageSize(10)
              .execute();
          List<Course> courses = response.getCourses();
          System.out.println(courses);
          if (courses == null || courses.size() == 0) {
              System.out.println("No courses found.");
          } else {
              System.out.println("Courses:");
              for (Course course1 : courses) {
                  System.out.printf("%s\n", course1.getName());
              }
          }
      }
  ```

  }

I belive nothing is wrong with authentication because whenever I run this piece of code, get an entry in dashboard on my app "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard"

[image: here is the image of what I am getting on dashboard]

I am new to Google class room and Its been a long time I am trying to integrating this no success so far, need help.

One more thing It says it is mandatory to have a G suite account (I dont get it where it is used, yet I have not created G suit account, is this the reason I am getting exception)

Please let me know If I am suppose to add more details on above senerio.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Gsuite accounts are found [here](https://gsuite.google.com/). Classroom API scopes are found in [Authorizing requests with OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/auth#OAuth2Authorizing)